# Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 20 - DNS resolution doesn't work

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, dns, ubuntu-20.04

**I posted my solution too.  I hope this saves someone else a lot of time.**

---

**I have an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 20.  DNS resolution never works, or fails a lot.**

My file /etc/resolv.conf has

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

The file is not a symlink, and I can certainly edit it to use *nameserver 8.8.8.8* ,

But the file periodically gets overwritten and the *127.0.0.53* (or something similar) is back.

I just want dns to work!

**See my solution below.**

Answer (score 1):

1. Get your nic's name from a config file.

   cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

On my system, amazon sets the nic name to ens5.

2. As root create new file: /etc/netplan/99-custom-dns.yaml
   with the following content.
   Replace *ens5* with your nic's name.

   ```
     network:
        version: 2
        ethernets:
            ens5:         
                nameservers:
                        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
                dhcp4-overrides:
                        use-dns: false
   ```
3. Reboot

   sudo shutdown -r now
4. Verify.  After the reboot you can try pinging something by name

   ping yahoo.com

or you can view the output of:

```
systemd-resolve --status
```

5. Done

Here's a link to the Amazon help doc, though it misses the nontrivial detail about your nic's name:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-static-dns-ubuntu-debian/